# Need help to identify a PCB connector

Tags: power-supply, connector, identification

I'm refurbishing an old Apple II Power Supply made by Astec. It's working now, but I damaged the connectors which connect the Live and Neutral wires to the Power Supply PCB. On the PCB are two posts, each about 1cm tall, and maybe 2mm in diameter, with a "bullet connector" like shape. The wires have what looks like simple cylinders which plug onto the PCB posts.

I can't find any reference to, or even images of such connectors using Google. Does anyone know what they are? I guess they might be proprietary to Astec, and possibly even obsolete, but before I do anything drastic, I'd like to try to replace them with the right ones.

Here you can see the connector in the foreground, beside the fuse:

[image]

Comment: Picture please? The best we can do without one is google with the info you gave us. If you post a pic we might recognize it.

Comment: We're way worse off than you without a photo.

Comment: Yep, I was waiting for that - I don't know how to paste an image - am looking into it now... D'oh!

Comment: Kind of reminds me of [this guy](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/60793-1/A100694TR-ND/265568), but it is not a PCB component... How large is the hole on the one you have?

Comment: I've seen the mating connector for that a few times, but I couldn't tell you what it's called.

Comment: Looks like it was some kind of molex connector, though it probably had a custom housing.

Comment: Looks like a 2mm banana plug

Comment: Email Steve Jobs and ask him...

Comment: Actually, Steve Woz is still around..he afterall was the original designer

Comment: OK, I'll have a look at 2mm banana plugs... thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for bullet or barrel connectors.  Try going to digikey in the terminals sub section : http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-barrel-bullet-connectors/1442843?k=bullet

Another source would be http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-contacts/1442670?stock=1

These would be crimp on (can be soldered) to wire, providing you a single barrel like connection.  You will need to use the search functionality to sort out what you are looking for specifically.  I would use molex for the manufacturer as they make an assortment of female connections for power, such as what you would see on vintage RC car battery packs.   Just search google images for "rc battery pack connectors".